# Read a csv file with column name as one column cell values

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to read a CSV file in this format:

```
"name","foo"
"class","9"
"age","34"
"gender","F"
```

into a resulting dataframe like this:

```
   name  class  age  gender
0  foo     9    34    F
```

Comment: This is not a CSV file. Are you going to have multiple records in a file or a single record mentioned as in your response.

Comment: @Jitendra I have multiple records in my csv file . My csv file contain around 30 rows with different tag names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=False, header=None)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(df[1]).T) 
header = df[0]
header.name = None
df2.columns = header
df2.index = [0]
```

Now `df2` contains:

```
   name class age gender
0  foo     9  34      F
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('names.csv') as csvfile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
...     for row in reader:
...         print(row['first_name'], row['last_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below option.

```
configreader = csv.DictReader(open(configuration_file_path))
        result = {}
        for row in configreader:
            for column, value in row.iteritems():
                result.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
       print "    ".join(result.keys())
       for index in range(len(result["name"])):
           print "{0}->{1}-->{2}".format(index, result["name"][index],result["foo"][index])
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have first column as header and second column as value, below option could be useful

```
fhandle = open("d:\\a.csv")
result = {}
for row in fhandle:
    row = row.strip()
    item = row.split(",")
    if len(item) > 1:
        if item[0] not in result:
            result[item[0]] = []
        result[item[0]].append(item[1])
print "    ".join(result.keys())
for index in range(0,len(result.values()[0])):
    for key in result.keys():
        print result[key][index] + "    ",
    print "\n",
```